# Are there any critical analyses of Hindu myths?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, rituals, critique

First of all, myths do not mean tall tales because by 20th century people realized that all the myth around the world has a secondary element of truth.

Now, there is an incident in Greek myth *Odyssey* where Odysseus and his companions got stuck on a island. The island had a lot of cattle and they happened to be [dearer to God Helios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cattle_of_Helios), so killing them or consuming them was strictly forbidden. His companions anyways eat them, and made Helios furious, and they all died after Helios cursed them.

Since consumption of cattle was not forbidden in Greek culture, scholars explained this incident as an indication in change in food habits of Greeks at that time may be because cattle became scarce.

Similarly, there are many incidents within the Hindu epics Ramayana and Mahabharata like the Agni-pariksha of Sita, various incidents of Gandharva vivaha, etc., which the writers deliberately included to maintain some kind of *status quo* or describe some sort of social fabric? Or are these incidents simply included to justify existing [rituals](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1057/978-1-137-53825-3_12)?

So my question is:

**Did any one do a comprehensive critical analysis of Hindu myths within the purview of social, moral and ethical framework?**

Comment: 1. Scientific speculation 2. Too broad. You may mention specific incidents that you consider myths  3. Ramayana and Mahabharata are not myths.

Comment: This is a valid question. OP asked: 'Did any one do critical analysis of Hindu myths...?' -- Asking if a comprehensive study was done on any topic is neither "too broad" nor "scientific speculation."

Comment: @sv critical analysis implies scientific speculation and atheistic critique.  Critical analysis in the form of Astika commentaries already exist.

Comment: @moonstar2001 not true...critical analysis implies what purpose the Ramayana and Mahabharata serve.  Astika commentaries start with disowning Vedas and they often delve in the realm of the philosophy and I am not interested in that side. Yaska was the first person who wrote first commentary on Vedas, so I was asking on the similar line if someone has done any analysis on the Ramayana and Mahabharat

Comment: "which the writers **deliberately included** to maintain some kind of status quo or describe some sort of social fabric" - is this your opinion ?